# how to get the value from one directive to another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is my index.html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <search myname="myval" change-client='client()'></search>
<pagination></pagination>
  </body>

</html>
```

and app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.directive('search', function($rootScope) {
    return {

      scope:
      {
        myname:'=',
        changeClient : '&'


      },
       restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input type ="text" ng-model = "bankname">{{myname}}</div>',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

        scope.$watch('bankname',function(newVal){
        //alert("inside search"+scope.bankname);
         $rootScope.myname = scope.bankname;
         scope.changeClient();
          });


        }

    };
});
app.directive('pagination', function($rootScope) {
    return {

        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><h1>from pagination</h1></div>',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      // alert("inside pagination"+$rootScope.myname);

        scope.$watch('bankname',function(newVal){
        alert("inside pagination"+scope.bankname);

          });


        }

    };
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {

 $scope.client = function() {

 $scope.myval = $rootScope.myname;
// alert("in controller"+$scope.myval);
 }
});
```

below is the link for plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/RdKOKMV5Cf6yTXx5PZMt?p=preview

and what I am trying to get is when I enter some value in text box I am getting that value in search directive but not in pagination directive link function how to get the value in pagination directive link function please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the scope of MainCtrl. directive's scope is a child of MainCtrl's.

Try this:

```
app.directive('search', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><input type ="text" ng-model = "bankname">{{myname}}</div>',
  };
});

app.directive('pagination', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><h1>from pagination</h1></div>',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('bankname',function(oldVal, newVal){
        if(oldVal !== newVal) {
          alert("inside pagination : "+scope.bankname);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not find any changes in above code other than my code, can u please explain this.

Comment: I'm removed isolated scope on search directive so that input data is binding to scope of MainCtrl. and using it on pagination directive.

Comment: I am getting undefined value for scope.bankname.But I have to use isolated scope for my other part of code, can we achieve this without removing isolated scope

Comment: That's a notice when the searchfield is empty, you can either ignore this or add a error_reporting(E_ERROR); or something.

Comment: edited. now alert will be displayed if input data is changed.

Comment: yes getting value in alert but I need Isolated scope because I am using it in other place of my code so how to do this by including isolated scope.

Comment: please think about what isolated means. if you are using isolated scope, it's isolated with others. so only child directive can access the parent's isolated scope like this:


    <search myname="myval">
        <pagination></pagination>
    </search>
. is this what you want?